# Disable button using ngdisabled via greater than lesser than operation angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I Have a situation based on the sum of a group textboxes the button should be enabled and disabled in angularjs

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="{{goalAA-goalAB--goalAC--goalAD--goaAE}} > 100" ng-click=clicked()>Save changes</button>
```

if the value is more than 100 the disabled is not set to true
the fiddler goes here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7g0evfk3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove square brackets in ng-disabled. You can find more information about ng-disabled directive in [angularjs documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="goalAA-goalAB--goalAC--goalAD--goaAE > 100" ng-click="clicked()">Save changes</button>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m9vn4bcp/1/)**

Comment: @Dennis Glad to help.